# How to compare the effect of a continuous predictor versus a binary predictor on a continuous variable?

Tags: regression, binary-data, continuous-data, predictor

How to compare the effect of a continuous predictor versus a binary predictor on another variable through regression?

For example, we're predicting log(cd4) in the case of HIV infected patients.

Having treatment X increases the log(cd4) by 0.23. A continuous random variable such as time measured in days, for each unit increase affects the log(cd4) by 0.10.

May one say that the time effect is actually stronger given that you can only choose between giving treatment or not, but each 2 days that pass is essentially equivalent to being on treatment versus not being on treatment?

Let's say for example, we're doing a strange study where we're only allowed to measure for 2 hours and the phenomenon is only constrained to two hours. This isn't a missing data situation. Just one day isn't allowed to happen since there's an apocalypse hypothetically. We run a regression and a unit increase in days increases the log(cd4) by .98 but active treatment only increases the log(cd4) by 0.05. 
Since we're never going to reach one day, we only have 2/24 of a day, can you say that the time effect is even outweighs anything given the situation that you'll never observe the effect of the coefficient which is for an entire day?

Is comparing whether the effect of time versus treatment given the difference in their variable nature, valid?

Comment: Regression coefficients are expressed in the units of the underlying *x* variates, i.e., for a given change in *x*, *y* changes that amount. If the units of the *x* variates differ, then the resulting coefficients are not directly comparable. One quick and dirty heuristic is to compare the associated t-values for the parameters. Those are standardized metrics which permit direct comparisons.

Comment: Maybe of interest: [Scaling regression inputs by dividing by two standard deviations](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/standardizing7.pdf). If you'r binary explanatory variable is (relatively) balanced you don't need to standardise it. Standardising the continuous variable provides a rough direct comparison to a binary indicator as discussed.